# Decrypting VB.Net (14) System.Security.Cryptography salted password in PHP to Login to Android App

Tags: php, vb.net, hash, cryptography, salt

I have read up on tons of samples and answers (and even more on how cryptography works) but none answers my scenario. I am creating a new user from desktop app in VB.Net. User need to use Android for a small part to update a valuation where a PC is not available (Web app is not an option unfortunately)

I have no problem in desktop app, all works fine. I am using a PHP page to handle the login and other data related actions in Android, also no problem. I did however had to change password to normal strings etc to read the passwords. I need to let PHP read the saved salted string (different salt for each password - all randomly generated, no salt the same for more than 1 user) linked to that particular password.

I have played around with the code for some time now to try and use the same kind of function in PHP but I am totally lost on how to convert the .net part to be used in PHP.

My .net code looks like this -

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Module modSecurity

Public Function GetSaltedHash(pw As String, salt As String) As String
    Dim tmp As String = pw & salt

    ' or SHA512Managed
    Using hash As HashAlgorithm = New SHA256Managed()
        ' convert pw+salt to bytes:
        Dim saltyPW = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmp)
        ' hash the pw+salt bytes:
        Dim hBytes = hash.ComputeHash(saltyPW)
        ' return a B64 string so it can be saved as text 
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(hBytes)
    End Using

End Function

Public Function CreateNewSalt(size As Integer) As String
    ' use the crypto random number generator to create
    ' a new random salt 
    Using rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
        ' dont allow very small salt
        Dim data(If(size < 7, 7, size)) As Byte
        ' fill the array
        rng.GetBytes(data)
        ' convert to B64 for saving as text
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(data)
    End Using
End Function
```

Within my form I will create the hashed password and salt as follow -

```
strPasswordNew = txtPassword.Text

        Dim NewPWD As String = strPasswordNew ''Actual password
        strSaltPWD = CreateNewSalt(SaltSize) ''Salt pwd
        Dim SaltPWDHash As String = GetSaltedHash(NewPWD, strSaltPWD) ''New   pwd now hashed
```

The password and the salt is saved to database under their own fields - salt and pwd.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated please.

Comment: In general it is a security error if passwords are available as plain text. SO, why do you need them as plain text?

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: @Zaph, thank you for your response, I do not need the passwords in plain text, I need to compare them with the hashed and salt passwords when user logs in on android app. These pass and salts is however created in the .net desktop app which means I need to use the same "formula" to confirm the correct passwords has been entered on the android app. This is done using php scripts connecting and logging in. I have only changed the pass to plain text to test the connection and to test the login parts. This is very unsafe though.

Comment: I will however delve deeper into this as when I read up on this when we started the .net app it was recommended that the way above is a very safe way. Apparently not.